# How to write a C++ Callback interface to a Fortran or C Function?

Tags: c++, c

Let's think the callback function signature which a dll expects and can't be changed looks like this:

```
double f(double *x)
```

What I wan't to create is a simple function pointer (or an intermediate layer), to create a compatible function pointer out of, let's say the following (using a closure):

```
 double f(double *t, double n, double x);
 //Result at runtime: double f(double *t);
```

- The values in the closure are readonly
- In general it should just be a c - funtion pointer out of a std:function or a lambda or something that works and can be passed as a callback with the given signature
- An intermediate layer over the fortan function is also possible, for example [scipy](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.10.1/scipy/integrate/__quadpack.h) looks to be doing something like this. An interface like double `double func(double x, void *user_data)` would also be OK, at least I found some examples how to work with that from C++.

I tried `std::function<double(double *)> f_lambda = std::bind(f,  std::placeholders::_1,n,x);` but I can't get a simple function pointer out of this closure.

So the actual question is how to get something like this working (of course with a real closure) and preferably in a simple way. I do not have any issue with new (some object) and delete (some object) if necessary. It should just be simple to use and understandable to someone with very limited C++ knowledge.

**Pseudo Code**

```
double *some_closure(double f(double *t), double n, double x)
                  {//do something on func;
                   //output a double*(double *t) function pointer}
```

Comment: Standard C does not support closures, so there is no way to convert anything that involves closures into a plain C function pointer. That's why a lot of callbacks use that `double func(double x, void *user_data)` form - to allow the caller to shove any extra data into that `user_data` pointer (and convert it back into whatever they need)

Comment: @UnholySheep I know that a lot of libraries accept a function pointer like `double func(double x, void *user_data)`. For example the fortran based library quadpack doesnt't by default, but with some code in between it's obviously possible. I am searching for the simplest possible way (with or without a C(++) interlayer) to accomplish something similar. If I do understand the basic principle of https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.10.1/scipy/integrate/__quadpack.h I wouldn't ask this question. ...Well maybe a comfortable and simple way from C++, which I don't have practically any knowlege of.

Comment: @max9111 *I know that a lot of libraries accept a function pointer like `double func(double x, void *user_data)`*  No, from the C++ perspective they accept a function pointer like `extern "C" double func(double x, void *user_data)`.  Which is why there are a lot of ways you **can't** use them in C++..

Comment: @Andrew Henle Absolutely True, but how do the scipy guys (in a simple code..., the already did this) manage to get a `double func(double x, void *user_data)` around quadpack? It is also a fortran lib and somehow they get that interface (and a Python interface too which is not part of the question).

Comment: @max9111 This: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html? It's Python, not C and not C++ trying to call C.

Comment: @Andrew Henle I know there is some Python in between but https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.10.1/scipy/_lib/src/ccallback.h (around line 350) seems to do exactly what I want, in this case with some python interaction, which I have to avoid. Some old libs like quadpack are used for 40+ years, I honestly can't belive (but I don't know), that there isn't some sort of workaround for a function closure. Well programming everything in source code is a possibillity, but..... If there is no other possibility I have to search for another workaround. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: @max9111 And at [line 351](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.10.1/scipy/_lib/src/ccallback.h#L351) there's a `user_data` element exactly like UnholySheep's comment.

Comment: @Andrew Henle Yes, they define it there and create a wrapper around libs (like quadpack, which are not providing `void *user_data`. Maybe quite the same as Ivella described.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254170/discussion-between-max9111-and-andrew-henle).

Comment: @max9111: The integration callbacks (C port of quadpack) have such a userdata pointer already, it's not something that scipy needs to emulate: https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/roots.html#providing-the-function-to-solve

Comment: @Ben Voigt I switched to that https://github.com/ESSS/cquadpack. But for stackoverflow it is very useful to have a direct solution and a workaround  solution as an possible answer (and why it is in this case worth to search for alternative libs, or modify them). Ideally an answer should also be useful to someone who can't switch the library and have to live with what is provided. (It is possible, what I am asked for, but with significant drawbacks...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that in pure C++ (i.e. without messing with generating binary code at runtime, thing that only JIT compilers and malwares usually do, and is frowned upon from the perspective of security and portability).

What you can do is store the value of `n` and `x` in global or static variables, (possibly thread-local, if you know the C program will not call the function from another thread) and define a plain function or static member function with the required signature that uses the global variables `n` and `x`.

EDIT: answering the question in the comment, this is what I managed to put together:

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace {
    // Like std::invoke, but only works with std::function cast to void*.
    template <class Ret, class... Args>
    Ret invoke_ptr(void* ptr, Args... args) {
        return (*static_cast<std::function<Ret(Args...)>*>(ptr))(args...);
    }
}

// "Transforms" an std::function<Ret(Args...)> into a function pointer and a void* context.
// func must live as long as the returned void*
template <class Ret, class... Args>
std::tuple<Ret (*)(void*, Args...), void*> function_pointer_from_std_function(std::function<Ret(Args...)> &func) {
    return {&invoke_ptr, static_cast<void*>(&func)};
}


//// TESTING:
int main() {
    auto captured = "hello";
    std::function<int(int, float, std::string)> func([&] (int a, float b, std::string c) {
        std::cout << captured << ' ' << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << std::endl;
        return 42 - a;
    });

    // func_ptr here is a function pointer, with the following type:
    // int(*)(void*, int, float, std::string)
    auto [func_ptr, context] = function_pointer_from_std_function(func);

    auto returned = (*func_ptr)(context, 100, 66.6, "this is love");
    std::cout << returned << std::endl;
}
```

it prints:

```
hello 100 66.6 this is love
-58
```

Comment: An `extern "C" double f(double d, void *user_data)` implemented in C++ would be a lot easier to use while being thread-safe.

Comment: Yes, but OP specifically said they can't change the interface implemented by the library they are using. And there is no need to declare it as `extern "C"`, because the visibility and symbol name of the function doesn't matter, as it would be used via it's pointer.

Comment: I found a solution quite like have you described with ups and downs.  https://caiorss.github.io/C-Cpp-Notes/passing-lambda.html
Can you expain how to get a function pointer and a context pointer (´void *something) out of a std:function?

Comment: @max9111 That is an entirely new question. But the gist of it is that first you create a plain function that takes a pointer to an `std::function` and call it: that gives your function pointer. Then you simply take a pointer to the `std::function` and cast that to `void *`, that is your context pointer. Of course, you have to ensure the object will still exists when it is called, what may involve allocating or moving it to the heap before taking the pointer.

Comment: Something more general as the `FunctionObject` in this example. Basically create some funtion pointer and some  `void user_data` representing the context out of a std:function wich can be passed to some C-function.  C++ syntax is currently not my friend, a simple example complicated enough (some std:function anywhere) would be realy helpful.

Comment: I know, I looked at high ranked answers where the point was "an empty closure is a closure" -> syntactically correct, but absolutely not helpful..... And also the scipy source code which uses a workaround like you described. Therefore I believed my question is easily to be answered (I'm just to stupid).